# Do spring boot profiles play nicely with env variables?

Tags: spring-boot

I know it's possible to set the "profile" for springboot by using a switch at the command line (great for tests) but is it possible to set this "profile" using a system env variable also/ instead?

I'm doing deployments and I'd prefer to have a env var on the box that states what profile spring boot should be using / etc

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable to specify specific profiles or `SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT` to specify the default profile to use if none are active.

Comment: excellent! do you have a link to the docs that show this in action? or could you add a short snippet here?

Comment: The documentation discusses it a little [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config). There isn't really any code that is needed, simply EXPORT SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev then run your app.